# How can define the stun server two public IP address setting in openfire without admin console only by using database and what will be two address?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, stun

I am implementing the voice chat feature using xmpp openfire plugin. I am able to upload the stun server and jingle nodes plugin jar files on server. We can change set the configuration of stun server setting using admin console of openfire. But I can't login using admin console due to forgot password. So, I want to set the stun server setting using database. **My main issue is that there are need to define the two public IP address and ports in configuration, but any site has only one public address. So, What will be the primary and secondary IP address of a website.**

The below configuration defined openfire.ofProperty database table for localhost in LAN. It detected automatically by openfire.

```
'stun.address.primary', '192.168.12.31'
'stun.address.secondary', '192.168.2.1'
'stun.local.enabled', 'true'
'stun.port.primary', '3478'
'stun.port.secondary', '3479'
```

But, In case of live server what will be the above parameters.

If anyone have idea. Please reply 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: *"But I can't login using admin console due to forgot password."* - Wouldn't you be better off fixing that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need the second IP address for STUN connectivity. The secondary address exists for clients to determine the NAT type/classification. If you are using an ICE or ICE like methodology for accomplishing P2P, one STUN address should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I will try to define as per your suggestion. :)